# How to correctly specify spring config as VM argument in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I have the following application.yml file

```
plaintext:
   server:
      port: 8085
```

I am trying to run the application on eclipse but I get following error:

```
 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'plaintext.server.port' in string value "${plaintext.server.port}"
```

I dont think I am specifying my spring config correctly.

The application.yml is located in folder src/main/resources.

I put the following as VM argument when running in eclipse:

-Dspring.config.name="src/main/resources/application.yml"

Comment: Is your *current directory* the directory containing `src`? It would likely be better to specify fully qualified name. Better yet, don't specify `spring.config.name`, since `application.yml` will be loaded from classpath anyway.

Comment: i am not running on cmd line, from eclipse directly.

Comment: What does that have to do with what I said? When running from Eclipse, the program is still run with a current directory, otherwise what did you expect the relative path you specified to mean?

Comment: in that case the current dir does contain src

Comment: It should be `spring.config.location`, not `spring.config.name`. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files